# Find password protected PDFs

Tags: linux, unix, pdf, software-rec

I have a large number of PDFs and would like to find the ones that are password protected.

Tools like pdfinfo can detect password protection but do not have a specific exit status to script this process:

```
# pfdinfo pwprotected.pdf
Command Line Error: Incorrect password
# echo $?
1
# pdfinfo broken.pdf
<some error messages>
# echo $?
1
```

Are there any tools that can be used to easily identify password protection on pdfs? Otherwise I can still grep for the "Incorrect password" line and fix up my own script.

Comment: Just wrap it in a function that `grep`s stderr for "Incorrect password"?

Comment: I think you can do something like;
`find -type f -iname \*.pdf -exec grep -alP 'R\/Encrypt \d+ \d+' {} \;`
Though, I'm not sure how performance efficient that is.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath that comes with mostly false positives for me, but thanks anyway. I will probably just shellglue something with pdfinfo.